# Issue in java lazy stream construction

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was looking at [this](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/30/a-quick-trick-to-make-a-java-stream-construction-lazy/) link for lazy stream construction and tried using it for one of my cases.

My primary stream has some operations that are needed to be done on [Stream.onClose()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#onClose-java.lang.Runnable-).

In my custom logic, I use Iterator from [Stream.iterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator--) for stream processing.

This worked fine consuming the actual Stream. But, when I used [Stream.flatMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) for constructing a lazy stream, `onClose` function gets called when I start iterating, which in-turn creates problems for me.

I tried this in zulu-opendjk 1.8.0_222 and 13. I am facing this exception in both the environments.

[image]

You can reproduce the problem with the below code.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class TestStreamIterator
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Stream<String> stream1 = getStream();
        stream1.iterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);

        Stream<String> stream2 = Stream.of(1).flatMap(integer -> getStream());
        stream2.iterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Stream<String> getStream()
    {
        List<String> values = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

        MyIterator iterator = new MyIterator(values);
        Stream<String> stream = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.NONNULL | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE), false).onClose(iterator::close);

        return stream;
    }

    private static class MyIterator implements Iterator<String>, AutoCloseable
    {
        private Iterator<String> iterator;

        public MyIterator(List<String> values)
        {
            iterator = values.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public String next()
        {
            return iterator.next();
        }

        @Override
        public void close()
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Should not come here");
        }
    }
}
```

My understating is, when using `flatMap`; `close` method of `Stream.of(1)` only should be called. Not of the stream created inside `flatMap` function.

I was expecting the `onClose` function to be invoked only when the stream is closed. But, I am not sure where the stream is getting closed.

Any help on solving this case would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call **`flatMap(integer -> getStream())`** here:

```
Stream<String> stream2 = Stream.of(1).flatMap(integer -> getStream());
stream2.iterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

You are calling this method:

> **Iterator**
>
> **`<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper);`**
>
> *Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element. **Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream**. (If a mapped stream is null an empty stream is used, instead.)*

So as the documentation says, the mapped stream you pass into this method (from `getStream()` which is a Stream over a `MyIterator`) will be closed, which it is, then (as defined in `onClose` of that Stream) it calls `MyIterator.close()` which throws the exception.

---

Addressing your comment since you don't seem to follow:

```
Stream<String> stream2 = Stream.of(1).flatMap(integer -> getStream());
```

Creates a stream that will lazily map to the contents of a sub-stream when you read it. When that sub-stream is loaded into the main stream the sub-stream will be closed.

```
stream2.iterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

You read from the main stream, which maps to the sub-stream, which reads all the sub-stream then closes the sub-stream which then calls `Stream.onClose()` which calls `MyIterator.close()`

Comment: In my actual case, I have a resource opened in that iterator. So, if its closed, I cant access data that i want.
Also, **mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream**, I haven't accessed the data from the Stream using iterator. @xtratic

Comment: @suraj1291993, it seems that what should be closed are the resources created by the stream then, not the stream itself.

Comment: @DidierL I agree with you. Resources opened internally should be closed internally. To ensure that, the primary stream I return will have handling on `onClose` to close them.
If this snippet is executed `Stream.of(1).flatMap(integer -> getStream()).forEach(System.out::println)`, you can see that `stream.close` will be called after stream is consumed. i.e., all the elements in the stream are iterated and processed.

Comment: @suraj1291993 I have tried to explain further in my answer.

Comment: @suraj1291993 Incorrect. Only running `Stream.of(1).flatMap(integer -> getStream()).forEach(System.out::println)` nothing is printed, since the sub-stream closing throws the Exception.

Comment: @suraj1291993 Please accept this answer as it answers all your questions